# App Settings from Web.config in WCF Service returning null

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I am having an issue retrieving app settings from my web.config file in a WCF service I am creating. When calling my settings, I am retrieving a null value. Digging into the object also shows that there are no keys in `AppSettings` list.

This issue has a few posts around SO/Google, and I have incorporated all the suggestions, but to no avail. Here is my current position and what I have tried:

web.config:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />

    <!-- CRM Creds -->
    <add key="CrmUrl" value="[removed]"/>
    <add key="CrmUser" value="[removed]"/>
    <add key="CrmPass" value="[removed]"/>

  </appSettings>...
```

Methods of calling the settings:

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmUrl"]

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmUrl"]
```

The file I am calling from is within a folder, whereas web.config is in the root. I understand `WebConfigurationManager` could find this regardless, but I am having no luck.

Code:
`%projectfolder%/Client/Client.cs`

Config: `%projectfolder%/web.config`

I have run out of things to try and have used up all my Google-fu. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: looks ok your file, is the web.config file in same place of your .svc file, out of bin folder?

Comment: @RicardoPontual My .svc file is in `localhost/Client/Service.svc` (excuse the confusing names) and my web.config is in `localhost/web.config`

Comment: try to put in same folder.

Comment: I put it in the same folder, still no luck..

Comment: really strange... try to open the file passing the path, like this: WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)